# Replacing image inside a table cell doesn’t work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table in which rows are added dynamically using jQuery (latest row on top using prepend). If it is an errorLine, text in the first column will be “x”. If it is a successLine the text in the first column will be numerals like 1,2,3…

If the latest row is an errorLine, I need to apply background color (using class “firstErrorLine”) and replace the text “x” with an image.  At the same time I need to remove image from all other lines and replace image with text “x”. I tried multiple jQuery approaches but didn’t work. Following is one of the failed approaches.

```
//$("#tblVisualAidResult tbody tr td:first img").hide().parents("tr td:first").html('x');
```

Any thoughts how we can achieve this?

**[Demo – jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z86dq/31/)**

**jQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{


function styleFirstErrorLine(isFailureExist)
{

            $("#tblVisualAidResult tbody tr").removeClass('firstErrorLine');

            //$("#tblVisualAidResult tbody tr td:first img").hide().parents("tr td:first").html('x');

            if(isFailureExist)
            {               
                $("#tblVisualAidResult tbody tr:first").addClass('firstErrorLine');

                var firstCell = $("#tblVisualAidResult tbody tr:first td:first");
                $(firstCell).html('<img width="50" height="50" class="errorImage" src="../images/Error2_BMP.JPG"/>');
            }
  }

styleFirstErrorLine(true);


});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="tblVisualAidResult" class="resultLog" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
    style="width: 100%; display: table; background-color: rgb(229, 219, 226);">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="Heading3" style="width: 20%;">
                Serial No
            </td>
            <td class="Heading3" style="width: 30%;">
                Container ID
            </td>
            <td class="Heading3">
                Status
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="Normal">
            <td style="padding-left: 5px">
                x</td>
            <td>
                TEST4
            </td>
            <td>
                Case Label does not Exist
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Normal">
            <td style="padding-left: 5px">
                2
            </td>
            <td>
                182145011
            </td>
            <td>
                Received 2 of 2 of work lot S318214501
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="Normal">
            <td style="padding-left: 5px">
                <img width="50" height="50" class="errorImage" src="../images/Error2_BMP.JPG"></td>
            <td>
                test3
            </td>
            <td>
                Case Label does not Exist
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Normal">
            <td style="padding-left: 5px">
                <img width="50" height="50" class="errorImage" src="../images/Error2_BMP.JPG"></td>
            <td>
                test2
            </td>
            <td>
                Case Label does not Exist
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Normal">
            <td style="padding-left: 5px">
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                182145029
            </td>
            <td>
                Received 1 of 2 of work lot S318214501
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Normal">
            <td style="padding-left: 5px">
                <img width="50" height="50" class="errorImage" src="../images/Error2_BMP.JPG"></td>
            <td>
                test1
            </td>
            <td>
                Case Label does not Exist
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you're after, but try something along the lines of `$("#tblVisualAidResult img").replaceWith('x');`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/f5QC8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, you should use `td:first-child` instead of `td:first`.

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h2LTB/)**